# Hiding elements when form (menu select choice is empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, twig

I got a menu select of ''subjects'' generated by a form, I want to hide some stuff in the twig while the user didn't choose anything from the menu select.
This is my form :

```
class CollapsideColleFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('colles', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'PACESColleBundle:Colle',
            'attr' => array( 'class' => 'browser-default colles' ),
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'label' => false,
            'group_by' => 'matiere',
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une colle' ));
}
}
```

The twig :

```
<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
<!-- Menu SELECT OF COLLES -->
<legend> Choix de la colle</legend> {{ form_widget(formColle.colles) }}
```

```
<!-- STUFF TO HIDE when the user didn't choose a ''colle'' -->
<!-- Note  -->
<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
<legend> Note </legend>
</fieldset>

    <!-- Classement  -->
<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
    <legend> Classement </legend>
</fieldset><br><br>

<!-- Moyenne  -->
<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
    <legend> Moyenne </legend>
</fieldset>

<!-- Médiane  -->
<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
    <legend> Médiane </legend>
</fieldset>

<!-- Major  -->
<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
    <legend> Major </legend>
</fieldset>

<!-- Minor  -->
<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
    <legend> Minor </legend>
</fieldset>
```

I am not very good with form I tried to give an Id to the form then with Javascript check if the menu select is empty but I don't know how to do it

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jQuery` to get the job done.

First of all, you must see the generated id for your elements. This is as simple as to right-click over them on your browser and select "Inspect". This will show you the DOM tree of the page with the node corresponding to the selected element highlighted.

Also, give a common CSS class to all items that you want to be able to hide.

Then you simply need to add a javascript code similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id-of-the-select-element').change(function(){
    if($(this).val())
    {
      $('.class-for-all-the-hiddable-elements').show();
    }
    else
    {
      $('.class-for-all-the-hiddable-elements').hide();
    }
  });
  $('#id-of-the-select-element').change();
});
```

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: I got multiples collapsides in each collapside a menu select (generated by a form)  with other stuff that I want to hide  I want to do the same for each menu select

Comment: Simply create a new `$('...').change(function(){...});` block for each of them and adjust ids and class names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery to do this :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
   <!-- Menu SELECT OF COLLES -->
   <legend> Choix de la colle</legend> 
   {{ form_widget(formColle.colles) }}
</fieldset>

<div class="hidden">
    <!-- Note  -->
    <fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
    <legend> Note </legend>
    </fieldset>

        <!-- Classement  -->
    <fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
        <legend> Classement </legend>
    </fieldset><br><br>

    <!-- Moyenne  -->
    <fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
        <legend> Moyenne </legend>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Médiane  -->
    <fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
        <legend> Médiane </legend>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Major  -->
    <fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
        <legend> Major </legend>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Minor  -->
    <fieldset style='display: inline; border: 2px solid deepskyblue;'>
        <legend> Minor </legend>
    </fieldset> 
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
     $('#idOfYourSelectInput').change(function(){
        $('.hidden').show();
     });
  });
</script>
```